# Exclude a <span> from link behaviour within a <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

Is it possible to exclude `<span>` tags from clicking within a normal hyperlink and attach a jQuery event to it?

Here's my code. I'm using bootstrap's list-group for a navigation element

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <a href="mylink.html" class="list-group-item node-tree" data-nodeid="0">
        <span class="icon fa"></span>
        <span class="icon node-icon"></span>
        Node 1            
    </a>
    <a href="mylink2.html" class="list-group-item node-tree" data-nodeid="1">
        <span class="icon fa"></span>
        <span class="icon node-icon"></span>
        Node 2
    </a>
    <a href="mylink3.html" class="list-group-item node-tree" data-nodeid="2">
        <span class="icon fa"></span>
        <span class="icon node-icon"></span>
        Node 3            
    </a>   
</ul>
```

I try to get the whole link clickable, but NOT the `<span>` containers inside, because the class "icon" needs an own click-function. Any idea (javascript, css, ...) is welcome!

Comment: Give it an id and you can change it however you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try prevent default so that click doesn't propagate to parent anchor function.

```js
$('.fa-genderless').click(function(event){

console.log('icon clicked');
//do something here.
    event.preventDefault();
    });
    
    $('.fa-file').click(function(event){

console.log('file icon clicked');
//do something here.
    event.preventDefault();
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group">
    <a href="mylink.html" class="list-group-item node-tree" data-nodeid="0">
        <span class="fa-genderless"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-file"></span>
        Node 1            
    </a>
    <a href="mylink2.html" class="list-group-item node-tree" data-nodeid="1">
        <span class="fa-genderless"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-file"></span>
        Node 2
    </a>
    <a href="mylink3.html" class="list-group-item node-tree" data-nodeid="2">
        <span class="fa-genderless"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-file"></span>
        Node 3            
    </a>   
</ul>
```